# Get last 5 item of sql results with Propel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, propel

I want to get the last 5 items of my search action. An example:

```
$quizzes = $user->getQuizs();
```

Now I would like to select the last 5 of that, is this possible with propel?
I tried ->getLast(5) but that's not correct.

Let's say I get 30 quizzes back, ordered by ID. I want to select the last 5 (with the highest id's .., these are the ones last created).

Comment: The last 5 in mysql right?

Comment: What is __last 5__?, you'd need to specify some kind of order to determine what the last 5 actually is.

Comment: Show us your query so we can work with that... If you indeed mean last 5 in mysql

Comment: Edit begin post, I want to select the 5 last created, so with the highest ID's..

Comment: You'll need a combination of [ordering](http://propelorm.org/Propel/reference/model-criteria.html#ordering-results) maybe `->orderById()`, and a limit `->limit(5)` but your question doesn't give enough information to give an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy peasy:

```
$quizzes = QuizQuery::create()->
    filterByUser($user)->
    orderByCreatedAt(\Criteria::DESC)->
    limit(5)->
    find()
;
```

This assumes you have a `created_at` column in your quiz table. You can then add this to your `User` model if you wish:

```
public function getLastQuizzes($limit = 5)
{
    return QuizQuery::create()->
        filterByUser($this)->
        orderByCreatedAt(\Criteria::DESC)->
        limit($limit)->
        find()
    ;
}
```